# select all table name and place inside a html dropdown

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <Select type="text"  style="width:220px; height: 30px;">
       <?php
       $con = new mysqli('sample', 'sample', 'sample', 'intelecrm_02_24_14_copy');

            if($con->connect_errno) {
                // error reporting here
            }
               $db = mysql_select_db('intelecrm_02_24_14_copy');
               $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
               $result = mysql_query($sql);
               while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                   $tables = $r['intelecrm_02_24_14_copy'];
                   echo '<option>'.$tables.'</option>';
                 }

       ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <button style="height: 21px; width: 100px;margin-top: 4px;"> Some button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here's my code.....i don't know what went wrong with this one. All I want is to select all table names from my database which I named Juice and place it inside a html dropdown (which is select) but i dont know why its not working.

I updated my question now....here's my latest code and nothing happens. The dropdown is still empty

Comment: First thing you'll want to do is use mysqli as the standard mysql driver has been/is being deprecated. You'll also problem want to put some error information in there somewhere, and `SHOW TABLES` will work just fine without `FROM $db`.

Comment: `$db` = boolean `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your PHP works, you want to move your echo code inside of the html SELECT element.

```
    <Select type="text"  style="width:220px; height: 30px;">
<?php
   $db = mysql_select_db('Juice');
   $sql = "SHOW TABLES from $db";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
       $tables = $r['Juice'];
       echo '<option>'.$tables.'</option>';
     }
     ?>

    </select>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question then?  You just say it's not working, but don't say what.  Html not there? Error in PHP?  Nothing loads?  Describe please.

Comment: I tried following your advice but it seems that it still doesn't load anything to the dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your post.

1. You're using the mysql driver which is depreacted, use mysqli instead.
2. You are echoing the `<option>` list before the `<select>`.
3. You are adding the return of a function to a query.

The following example will work.

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if($con->connect_errno) {
    // error reporting here
}

$result = $con->query("SHOW TABLES");

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<select>';
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo '<option>' . $row[0] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

In the example, I'm using the mysqli extension which is not only much better than the standard mysql extension, it's also not being deprecated as of right now. I've added in some error checking, as it's always important that you check for these sort of things.

The above **should**, in theory, do exactly what you need. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I did what you have told me but still nothing reflects on the dropdown.

Comment: Are you error checking? Are there tables in the database?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're printing the tags above the HTML. Try moving the PHP code inside the select tags. Next, you're using the handle `$db` inside your query. Maybe the following works (assuming you're connecting to your database somewhere using `mysql_connect`). I also doubt whether the field name is actually `Juice` (in your `$tables` statement); I filled in Belinda's suggestion for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <Select type="text"  style="width:220px; height: 30px;">
       <?php
       $db = 'Juice';
       $sql = "SHOW TABLES from $db";
       $result = mysql_query($sql);
       while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
       {
          $tables = $r['Tables_in_Juice'];
          echo '<option>'.$tables.'</option>';
       }
       ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <button style="height: 21px; width: 100px;margin-top: 4px;"> Filter Database</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The field name from show tables or show tables from $db is

`Tables_in_$db`

Try `$r['Tables_in_Juice']`

Comment: There are much larger problems than that. Also, the best solution would be to not return an associative array.